# How to insert values from into specific column in already available table using Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java program that reads lines from text file. I want to insert read lines into a columns for already available records in a table created in MySQL database.

The table that is already available consists of 4 columns. 
col1: pk, and auto increment number 
col2: text
col3: int
col4: text

Col4 is the value to be added after reading each line from the text file. I tried to use the following :

```
Query= "insert into db.table values (?)";
preparedStmt3 = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query);
```

Then after I read the line from the text file, I do the following;

```
 preparedStmt3.setString (3, line);
```

The column that I need to insert in is the 4th column. However, I get the following error:

```
DB_Error:_java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

My Question: How can I insert values in a specific column in MySQL database using Java wihtout affecting any value in the records (all other columns including the pk auto increment values are already inserted and need not to be changed at all).

Comment: try "insert into db.table(col2, col3, col4) values(?, ?, ?)"

Comment: I don't want to insert any values in the other columns.

Comment: then you need to mention like '.... db.table(col2) ...' then you need to set in java "setString(1, line). If you don't specify column names DBMS assumes you want to insert all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why have you used `3` as an argument to `setString()` The first argument of that function is the placeholder of parameter - the question mark in the query - this place holder starts from `1` and you only have a single placeholder.

Try,

```
preparedStmt3.setString (1, line);
```

because you only have a single place holder in your query. If this is not what you seek then rewrite your query. In fact, if you read the exception message, you will realise it: 
index out of range *(3 > number of parameters, which is 1).*

If you wish to insert multiple values, construct your query as:

```
`INSERT INTO table(c1, c2, c3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)`
```

and then

```
prepStatement.setString(1, val); // Sets value for c1 
prepStatement.setString(2, val); // Sets value for c2
prepStatement.setString(3, val); // Sets value for c3
```

Comment: How can I tell my code to insert this value in column number 4 ?? I used number 3 as the column number (I did not count the first column that is auto increment). When I tried your statement, I gotht he following error: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. Because the row in the database consist of 4 columns and I am inserting one only. How can I solve this issue, I don't want to insert values in the other columns, I need them as they are and they already have values.

Comment: Query: `INSERT INTO table(put_the_name_of_the_column_you_want_to_insert_in_here) VALUES (?)` and then use `prepStatement.setString(1, value);`

Comment: This inserted a new record. I want the program to start inserting in this column from the first available record (I already have, say, 100 record, I want the program to start inserting from the first available one) What happened is it starts to insert in a new record, say 101 in my example.

Comment: `INSERT` in that case is wrong choice, You need to use update query: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp